# Installation of brscan4 on ubuntu 17.04

Tags: drivers, package-management, scanner

I want to install brscan4 on an ubuntu 17.04 installation in order to scan documents over network using a Brother MFC-J6510DW.

During the preparation of the installation of brscan4 I asked myself about possible dependency issues.

According to the [brscan4 download site for MFC-J6510DW](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadend.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfcj6510dw_all&os=128&dlid=dlf006645_000&flang=4&type3=566) the current version is 0.4.4-4. I did not found any information, if this version is compatible with ubuntu 17.04.

According to the [preparation instructions](http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/before.html), to which the previous mentioned page links, brscan4 does not require the installation of sane-utils in contrast to brscan, brscan2, brscan3. Is this really true?

According to dpkg-deb this package does also not contain any dependendcy information.

As a result I have the following questions:
Does this package really not depend on sane-utils? Is it compatible with ubuntu 17.04? Should I expect compatibility with ubuntu 17.10?

Many thanks in advance!

*Note 1:* By just clicking the download link the package is downloaded via a http connection, but the link can be manually changed so that the transfer is done via a https connection.

*Note 2:* In the case of the printing I avoided the driver installation problem by using the driverless printing function of ubuntu 17.04.

**Appendix:** output of `dpkg-deb -I brscan4-0.4.4-4.amd64.deb`

```
 new debian package, version 2.0.
 size 74508 bytes: control archive=751 bytes.
       0 bytes,     0 lines      conffiles            
     240 bytes,     8 lines      control              
     944 bytes,    18 lines   *  postinst             #!/bin/sh
     622 bytes,    16 lines   *  postrm               #!/bin/sh
     185 bytes,     6 lines   *  preinst              #!/bin/sh
      86 bytes,     3 lines   *  prerm                #!/bin/sh
 Package: brscan4
 Version: 0.4.4-4
 Maintainer: Brother Industries, Ltd.
 Architecture: amd64
 Description: Brother Scanner Driver
  Copyright: 2008-2017 Brother Industries, Ltd. All Rights Reserved
  Brother sane backend Driver
 Provides: brscan
```